# Azure Trigger on Blob storage, extract EXIF (lat/long/direction...) data from image (Blob)

Tags: node.js, azure, triggers, blob, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to retrieve lat/long/rotation attributes from jpegs uploaded to Azure but can't get it.

current function on trigger:

```
module.exports = async function (context, myBlob) {
    context.log( myBlob);
};
```

the Trigger is on upload and I can get URI for the file uploaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally found a solution

1. you have to install "exif-parser" using npm
2. to access PowerShell or CMD using (Kudu)
3. go to “Advanced Tools”

[image]

4. Afterwards, launch the PowerShell debug console and navigate to the wwwroot folder of your app

[image]

5. then install your module "npm install exif-parser"
6. if any error show for"package.json" ignore it
7. go to you trigger or function app and test the module :)

> ```
> const exifParser = require('exif-parser');
> module.exports = async function (context, myBlob) {
>     context.log(myBlob);
>     var parser = require('exif-parser').create(myBlob);
>     var result = parser.parse();
>     context.log(result);
> };
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading the JPEGs with a reader, then there should be various EXIF format attributes that just need to be exposed.

If you are downloading the JPEG as binary, then I think you'll need to save the file and then read it back to get that EXIF info.

Try with using **Exif.js** JavaScript library

A JavaScript library for reading EXIF meta data from image files.

You can use it on images in the browser, either from an image or a file input element. Both EXIF and IPTC metadata are retrieved. This package can also be used in AMD or CommonJS environments.

For more reference follow this [github code](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js)